# Have to transform a bunch of csv in req format and store it in some other location with same name

Tags: shell, unix

I have some input `.CSV` files, `A_B_C_NFM001_20150729.csv`, `A_B_C_NFM002_20150729.csv`, `A_B_C_NFM003_20150730.csv`

I want output file also with the same name as input after performing below transformation on input file.

I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
TARGET=/path/transformed_dir
var=`echo /home/dbadmin/Indus_Project/PING_STATUS/A_B_C_*.csv | grep -oP '(?<=_)\d+(?=\.)'`
arr=($var)
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    awk -F, 'NR==1 { for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) sn[i]=$i }
     NR>1 { for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $1 "," sn[i] "," $i }'  A_B_C_*_$i.csv > $TARGET/A_B_C_*_$i.csv

done
```

but it's giving output file as `A_B_C_*_.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
target=path/transformed_dir
for srcname in path/PING_STATUS/A_B_C_*.csv
do
  basename=${srcname##*/}
  awk -F, 'NR==1 { for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) sn[i]=$i }
    NR>1 { for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $1 "," sn[i] "," $i }' "$srcname" >"$target/$basename"
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much.It really helped